# Java Recursion Matching Brackets from txt

Tags: java, recursion, matching, brackets

I have a problem with my code , can you help me please with this .. 
I want to make a recursion Matching brackets reading from txt .. 
this is my class , so i need help with the code if possible ,, thanks too much

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class MatchBrackets
{
    public static void main(String [] args) throws FileNotFoundException
    {

     boolean answer;
     String st;
     Scanner infile = new Scanner (new FileReader("MatchExpression.txt"));
     PrintWriter outFile = new PrintWriter ("MatchResults.txt");
     while (infile.hasNext())
     {
     st = infile.nextLine();
     outFile.println("Expression #" + ": " + st);

     answer = matchBrackets(st);
     if(answer == true)
     outFile.println( " Invalid Expression \n");
     else
     outFile.println( " The value of this expression is: "
     + answer);
     outFile.println(); outFile.println();
     }
     infile.close();
     outFile.close();
    }

    public static boolean matchBrackets (String str)
    {
     ArrayStack S = new ArrayStack(100);
     char ch;
     if ((str == null) || str.isEmpty()) {
         return str.isEmpty();
     }
     else {
     ch=str.charAt(0);
     if(ch=='{' || ch=='(' ||ch=='[' )
     { S.push(ch); }
     else if (ch=='}' || ch==')' ||ch==']' ){
     if(S.isEmpty())
     return false;
     switch(S.pop()){
     case '{': if(ch!='}') return false; break;
     case '[': if(ch!=']') return false; break;
     case '(': if(ch!=')') return false; break;
     }
     }
     return matchBrackets(str);
   }
    }
}
```

And the ArrayStack , included POP , PUSH , isEmpty ... etc

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: MatchExpression.txt (The system cannot find the file specified)
 at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
 at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Unknown Source)
 at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
 at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
 at java.io.FileReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
 at MatchBrackets.main(MatchBrackets.java:11)

Comment: do you have MatchExpression.txt in the same directory as your java file with main method

Comment: yes i have it .

Comment: Now i fixed the error , but i have another problem, once it see the first mismatch the rest will be mismatch `Expression #1:   ({[]}){[]}()
           Brackets match
Expression #2:   ( )(( )){([( )])}
           Brackets match
Expression #3:   [][][]{}()
           Brackets match
Expression #4:   ((( )(( )){([( )])}
           Brackets don't match
Expression #5:   ({[]}){[]}() // this should be correct
           Brackets don't match
Expression #6:   )(( )){([( )])}
           Brackets don't match
`

Answer (score 0):

So here's the problem, each recursive call you do:

```
ArrayStack S = new ArrayStack(100);
```

which means that each call you create a totally new stack. So you may want to create a new stack for each line you read from file and just pass this stack to your function.

Here is my solution. I assumed some dummy test strings instead of reading from file, it's basically the same thing. Just to test the function.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // test string
        String [] tests = {"[][][]{}()", ")(()){([()])}", "((()(()){([()])}", "({[]}){[]}()"};

        for (int i =0; i < 4; i++) {
            Stack<Character> stack = new Stack<>();
            System.out.println(matchBrackets(stack, tests[i], 0));
        }
    }

    private static boolean matchBrackets(Stack<Character> stack, String str, int i) {
        // if we reached the end of the string, then check if stack is empty or not
        if (i == str.length() && !stack.isEmpty()) return false;
        else if (i == str.length() && stack.isEmpty()) return true;

        if (str.charAt(i) == '(' || str.charAt(i) == '{' || str.charAt(i) == '['){
            stack.push(str.charAt(i));
            return matchBrackets(stack,str,++i);
        }  else {
            // if stack is empty, then the expression is false
            if (stack.isEmpty()) return false;
            char c = stack.pop();
            if ( (str.charAt(i) == '}' && c != '{') && (str.charAt(i) == ']' && c != '[') && (str.charAt(i) == ')' && c != '(') ) {
                return false;
            } else {
                return matchBrackets(stack,str,++i);
            }
        }
     }
}
```

Note: You can actually for example clear the stack for every expression instead of re-initializing it.